# Windows freeze when running Android emulator from Android Studio 2.3

Tags: windows-7, android-studio, emulator

I am using Android Studio in Windows 7. Whenever I start my AVD in Android Studio it freezes all my windows and then I have to reset my computer. It happens every time I start my virtual device. Before starting the virtual device everything works fine in Android Studio.

My system:

• Windows: Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1
• RAM: 8GB
• CPU: Intel i5 6500 Skylake
• Android Studio 2.3 Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
• JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
• JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains

s.r.o I have latest SDK and AVD installed. I also have Intel HAXM installed. The images I have tried to run on Android emulator are Android 5.1, x86/x86_64/armeabi. I have also played games for longer duration, so there is no CPU heating or anything.

Adding logs just before the system freezes after starting the AVD from Android Studio.

```
2017-03-24 12:16:08,284 [ 437243]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe, client support = true 
2017-03-24 12:16:13,454 [ 442413]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb 
2017-03-24 12:16:25,560 [ 454519]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null 
2017-03-24 12:16:26,597 [ 455556]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null 
2017-03-24 12:16:27,607 [ 456566]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null 
2017-03-24 12:16:28,618 [ 457577]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null
```

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: No, event logs were clear nothing unusual

Answer (score 0):

Same environment, cpu, ram, os, android studio version...
I have a nod 32 av with hips, host intrusion prevention system.
It picks up any attempt to access an external host and requests permission.
The avd and hips don't get along to well.
I disable it when I need to launch the emulator and everything works fine

Comment: Are you just saying that you have the same problem, or are you saying that you have the same problem and you fixed it? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.