# Android studio 3.0 heating up the laptop

Tags: laptop, freeze, overheating, android-studio

Since the last update of Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5, whenever I run it, my computer usage goes to almost 100% and laptop starts heating up. It freezes the entire PC. Has anyone else experienced it? I am using HP laptop with 6th gen i7 processor, 12 GB Ram, and 4 GB NVIDIA GTX graphic card. I have also tested this on my workstation (Dell Precision Tower 3620) and there also I notice within few min it starts to freeze. Especially, when I am working on XML file and creating layouts. It was working well when I was using their stable version.

I find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1191494/windows-freeze-when-running-android-emulator-from-android-studio-2-3) question similar to mine but in my case, it also heats up even without starting the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a a beta version. As the [download site](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) use the feedback tool to submit your issue. Meanwhile use the stable version as you can use them side by side.

You would have to dig more into it to figure out what's happening.